# apply reptitive sequence on multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have a multiindex dataframe where the inner most index can be of unequal length, I want to be able to add another column with repetitive values, but since the row counts are unequal, I am not able to so with:

```
df['marker'] = np.repeat([0,1,2], len(df), axis = 0)
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Here is my dataframe sample:

```
                               close
date    ticker      expiry_dt   
2016-07-27  BHEL    2016-07-28  147
                    2016-08-25  147
                    2016-09-29  150
2016-07-28  BHEL    2016-07-28  149
                    2016-08-25  147
                    2016-09-29  149
2016-07-29  BHEL    2016-08-25  149
                    2016-09-29  149
```

as you can see, the innermost index ('expirty_dt') is of unequal length. My desired output is:

[image]

I can maybe achieve this through a loop, but I have a large database and loop will be inefficient in doing so on a daily basis. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want

```
df.groupby(['date', 'ticker']).cumcount()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `np.repeat` expression produces an array with `3*len(df)` integers.

```
In [176]: np.repeat([0,1,2],3)
Out[176]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
In [177]: _.shape
Out[177]: (9,)
```

There is a different repeater

```
In [178]: np.tile([0,1,2],3)
Out[178]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
```

But there's still the question of whether the total number terms is right.

Comment: Yes, I guess np.tile is what I wanted. However, how do I overcome the issue with unequal row count.?

Comment: You want the number of unique dates, the first column, not the number of `close` values.  Maybe `len(df)/3` will work.  (I'm a numpy user, not pandas, so I'm guessing here).

Comment: I am thinking if this can be solved with groupby on the outer index and than applying a sequence on it. something like:
df['marker'] = df.groupby(level = 0, group_keys = False).apply(lambda x: np.arange(0,3))
this still does not work but wondering if that line of thinking is correct!